# Ad serving applications - alternative to Openx?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, openx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP based ad server ( alternative to OpenX )](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/php-based-ad-server-alternative-to-openx)

I have been serving ads via OpenX on a site for a while now but was recently hit by the SQL Injection vulnerability in the software which caused all sorts of problems.

I am looking for an alternative to OpenX.  It doesn't have to be open source, so far [Ad Butler](http://www.adbutler.com/)  is looking the most promising.

Any one have any suggestions for a decent ad serving solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of alternatives to OpenX but there is no one answer that fits everyone. If you're looking for a free alternative then you'll find plenty of options but I've found that you get what you pay for in terms of support and features.

If you're serving more than 100 million impressions each month and you need a dependable ad server then the list is pretty standard: DoubleClick, 24/7 OAS, AdTech and Adzerk. With the exception of Adzerk many of these ad servers require a contract and large monthly minimum to get started.

If you're serving between 1M and 100M then I think DoubleClick Small Business and Adzerk are good options since they are easy to signup for and don't require a contract. Adzerk has more support and is easier to use but DoubleClick is the bigger name. Also note that this site (StackOverflow.com) uses Adzerk.

Full Disclosure: I work for Adzerk so feel free to reach out if you'd like more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an administrator-centric ad server, try Dart for Publishers or Zedo.

If you are looking for an advertiser-centric ad server, try the new self-service ad servers out there such as Trafficspaces or iSocket.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,
we have released AdServerBeans MyAds v.0.4 (http://www.adserverbeans.com) a few weeks ago. You might be interested to take a look. It's open source and we position it as an alternative to OpenX in regard to features and purpose.
We definitely can't have SQL injection vulnerability since we are using Java's PreparedStatements.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at adwhirl - www.adwhirl.com - its an open source product which could serve your needs - it allows integration with admob and a few others.....

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and loved it.

http://www.agileoutsource.com/products/adnet.html

Simple and Effective.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://oasis.sourceforge.net

It's a good basic ad server with high performance.  Only problem is that it does not support newest PHP5.

Comment: That looks like quite a big problem...